# Posting on facebook friend's wall via facebook app doesnt work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish

I want to post on my facebook friends wall using my facebook app. I have already set the sufficient permissions like `publish_stream`, `offline_access` for it and I am using it's Graph API with PHP but it post to only those who are either the developer of the app or the administrator of the app. I dont know where i am doing the mistake. However one of my friend has successfully done it through objective c(iphone) code. I checked his code he was doing the same way as I am doing. Please help me over it. Here is my code and I am using facebook sdk 3.0 -:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sendTo = $_POST['friend'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $attachment = array('message' => $message, 'link' => $link );

    if($result = $facebook->api("/$sendTo/feed/",'post', $attachment))
    {
        $feedbackMessage = "Message sent to friend $sendTo";
    }
    else 
    {
        $feedbackMessage = "Oops something went wrong";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is your app still in sandbox mode?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would suggest that you will take a look at the recent update to facebook developers roadmap:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/
February 2013 Breaking Change:

"Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API 
We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see this blog post."

As mentioned by CBroe, the fact that only app administrators/developers can post might be related to the sandbox settings.

Anyway, the api should return a detailed error.

Comment: Yes, Actually i am enabling the sandbox mode in my app. that's why i am unable to post on friend's wall. it works when i disabled it. thanks CBroe for your great help And Thanks Guy Schlider for your detailed help, it will help me in the future, i hope.